# Как сделать бесконечную кнопку в discord.py

Tags: python, button, discord.py

Ищу и не понимаю. Вроде же можно, а не нахожу. В общем мне нужна кнопка, которая срабатывает не один раз и потом выдает "Ошибка взаимодействия". Она обязана выполняться каждое нажатие

Это код функции:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):    
    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Проверка!',timestamp = ctx.message.created_at)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, components = [Button(style = ButtonStyle.green, label = 'Create Ticket'), 
                                                Button(style = ButtonStyle.red, label = 'Delete Ticket')])

    responce = await bot.wait_for('button_click', check = lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)

    if responce.component.label == 'Create Ticket':
        await responce.respond(content = 'Ваш тикет создан!')
        # responce.component.disabled = False
        
    elif responce.component.label == 'Delete Ticket':
        await responce.respond(content = 'Ваш тикет удален')
```

Comment: Ты видимо не понял, когда я делаю кнопку и пишу что она делает. Запускаю бота, нажимаю на кнопку, она выполняется и больше не хочет выдавая "Ошибка взаимодействия". Это связано НЕ с кодом по крайней мере не тем что пишу я

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Непонятно что вы используете, скорее всего discord-components,
В документации написано про [бесконечные кнопки](https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components/guide/frequently-asked-questions)

Comment: Я успел разобрать сам примерно в тот же день когда задал вопрос. Однако спасибо тебе человеческая особь

Comment: @Gidrant Человеческая особь??? Нужно будет запомнить это новое вежливое обращение...